# Why does Google Play say app is "incompatible"

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I have an app that I want to install in my android phone. Unfortunately, it is marked 'incompatible'. I might try to upgrade the system to install the app, but **first I'd like to know the exact reasons the app is 'incompatible'**. I.e. what are the 'variables' my phone gets wrong to be unable to install the app.

**Is there a generic way to do that?**